# bootstrap 4 dropdown menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am building a UI in Bootstrap 4 and dropping onto WordPress. The navbar menu has proven to be a challenge. I have meticulously followed instructions on how to do this little retrofit, but have only limited success.

This I got working but with no dropdown

```
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-a-bootstrap-navbar-into-a-wordpress-theme--wp-33410
```

But the one with the Dropdowns I couldn't get going at all

```
http://simonpadbury.github.io/2016/03/09/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-dropdowns-for-wordpress.html
```

I feel like there is something missing, a step or two that is assumed perhaps.

Bootstrap 4 is loaded up and running in WordPress. In functions.php

```
require_once('navwalker/navwalker4.php');
```

which is what I am calling the Nav Walker for the Dropdown. (Thats the second link above that specifically addresses BS4 and the Dropdown in WP).

At the end of his Nav Walker file, there is this register,

```
register_nav_menu('primary', __('primary', 'promotionstoretheme'));
```

And finally there is this in the header.php

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'navbar',
      'container'      => false,
      'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
      'fallback_cb'    => '__return_false',
      'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
      'depth'          => 2,
      'walker'         => new bootstrap_4_walker_nav_menu()
      ) );
 ?>
```

I am really trying to understand it so I can formulate a clean and simple solution. Perplexed at this point. The names of the menu locations do not seem to matter much. Simple problem I am sure.

'preciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it should be kinda straight forward. I found a few posts that address this but they are either missing some step or they are referring to older versions of this software.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need this, but It was a big problem to me as well. I did somethings different, try it if you still need.

Follow the steps:

**functions.php**

```
// Register Nav Walker
require_once('bs4navwalker.php');
```

**bs4navwalker.php**

Lastest version:
https://github.com/dupkey/bs4navwalker

> I put the arquive bs4navwalker.php in the same root directory.

**header.php**

After **navbar-brand**

[...]

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.quickgames.com.br">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          </a>

             <?php
             wp_nav_menu([
               'menu'            => 'top',
               'theme_location'  => 'top',
               'container'       => 'div',
               'container_id'    => 'bs4navbar',
               'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
               'menu_id'         => false,
               'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
               'depth'           => 2,
               'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
               'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
             ]);
             ?>

            <!-- code for the badge START-->
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
            <!-- code for the badge END-->

            <form class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Procurar Produtos...">
              <span class="input_group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </span>
            </form>


           </nav>
```

**Wordpress admin**

[image: Choose Primary menu and set as top]

[image: That's my menu structure, works just fine]

I hope it helps.